# How to copy a value of register CR3

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I am confused. Take a look at code snippet below.

```
#pragma warning(2:4235)
int main()
{
       uint32_t cr3;
        __asm(
            "mov %%cr3, %%eax\n\t"
            "mov %%eax, %2\n\t"
            :"=m" (cr3)
            : /* no input */
            : "%eax"
        );
}
```

Compiled I see error

Error C2059 syntax error: : va2pa   C:\Users\usr\source\repos\1.cpp 80

How do I copy a value of `CR3` into variable `cr3`?

Comment: It may be worth mentioning  what's happening currently - does your code compile, does it crash, does it not do what you expect...

Comment: Also there's no need to clobber `eax`: you can directly read to the `cr3` variable, provided it's in a register (which you can arrange by an appropriate output specification).

Comment: Oh, you're using GCC syntax in MSVC?..

Comment: Are you sure you have enough privileges to read `CR3`? It might be accessible only from kernel mode. Also, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readcr3?view=vs-2019.

Comment: anyway read *cr3* is Privileged instruction and you can not execute it in user mode. only in driver. but *int main()* look like you write user mode app

Answer (score 3):

MSVC has intrinsics for everything so they can write a 64-bit kernel without inline asm.  (Because MSVC doesn't support inline asm in 64-bit mode).

Use `__readcr3()`.  [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readcr3?view=vs-2019). The intrinsic apparently works when compiling for 32 or 64-bit mode.

---

GNU C inline asm syntax isn't supported in MSVC.  In *Visual Studio*, you could use clang instead of MSVC; clang supports GNU extensions.

If you are doing that, just use an `"=r"` output so you can `mov` directly to the output operand; if the first or last instruction in your asm template is a normal `mov` (not to/from a control reg), you're usually doing it wrong.  Use better constraints to tell the compiler where to put or find data.

You *could* of course use MSVC inline asm syntax for this, but don't.  It's inefficient and a dead-end for portability (to other compilers, and to x86-64).

Comment: Could you show a snippet of code for MSVC. At the moment I see `1.exe: 0xC0000096: Privileged instruction.
`

Comment: @alexander.sivak: `mov` from control register is a privileged instruction, [as per the manual](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov-1).  You can only run this in kernel code, same as your GNU C inline asm.  If you want the value in user-space, you'd have to write a kernel module you can call, unless there's an existing system-call for it (very unlikely).